# Why is this simple code for passing a 2D array into the function giving me an error?

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote just a very simple code for passing a 2D array into a function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int proba(int a[][3]){
int x;
x=a[2][2];
return x;
int main(void) {
int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}};
int n;
printf("%d", a[2][1]);
n=proba(a);
printf("%d", n);
return 0;
}
```

It gives me this error on ideone.com

```
prog.c: In function ‘proba’:
prog.c:6:5: warning: ‘main’ is normally a non-static function [-Wmain]
int main(void) {
 ^
prog.c:13:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
}
```

Comment: You didn't close `proba`.  Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Using proper indentation would've helped you spot this.

Comment: yeah I saw it now, I will delete this question

Comment: Indenting code is not luxury nor a loss of time.

Comment: my code is indented, the thing is that when I copy from ideone.com to here, it loses the indent

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `proba` function closing `}` after:

```
return x;
```

Comment: wow, how did I miss that, thanks...